# How do I retrieve elements out an arrayList and also how to retrieve the length of an arrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am using an arrayList in one of my code. I am finding it difficult to retrieve elements out of an arraylist. it gives me an error when i use this:

`getit = newlist.get(g);`

Basically I want the string variable `getit` to store the value of the gth element of the arraylist called 'newlist' and then use it.

Could someone help with this? I am using Processing language for this.

All help will be appreciated,

Thanks in advance,

Amrita

Comment: Please show the declaration of **newList**, **g** and **getit**

Comment: -1 What is the error? Is it a compile-time error or run-time error?

Comment: I am copy-pasting a part of my code here:  for (int g = 0; g < newlist.size(); g++) {
            
     int sizeofword = 30;
     
       textFont(f, (freq[g]*0.7));
  
 String getit = newlist.1;
    sw= textWidth(getit);   I want getit to store the string so that i can find the textwidth of it. This is how I have declared them

Comment: I was using String getit = newlist.g; to retrieve the gth element out of the list..but it gives me errors

Comment: This question should be tagged 'Processing'. (I would like to get some Processing reps :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Either **newList** is not an **ArrayList**
Or **g** is not an **int**
Or **getit** is not a **String**

This is assuming error is a compile time error and not a run time error.

To get the length **myList.size();**

You should check the javadocs before posting questions:
[ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

So according to your post you are getting cannot convert from Object to String. This is because you are using an Object ArrayList instead of a String ArrayList. Use the following...

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("value");
int g = 0;
String val = myList.get(g);
```

Comment: To answer the other question, `newlist.size()` should return the length of the ArrayList object.

Answer (score 1):

maybe

```
getit = newlist.get(g-1);
```

lists start with 0. so if You are getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList newList = new ArrayList();
newList.add("One");
newList.add("Two");

System.out.println( newList.get(1) ); // retrieve second el.
System.out.println( newList.size() ); // get number of elements
```

works fine for me.

Please note, that lists in Java (and therefore in Processing) are 0 based. That means, the first index is 0.

Comment: I use the code like this:  for (int g = 0; g < newlist.size(); g++) { String getit = newlist.g;} It gives me an error saying newlist.g cannot be resolved or is not a field. I don't understand this error message. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to use `newList.get(g)` - with the 'get'-Keyword. (I. e. function call to be precise.) `newList.g` would mean something else in Java.

Comment: Thanks. I used  getit = newlist.get(g); and the error says 'cannot convert from Object to String' :(